# Installation was stuck after the partitioning screens have gone by, now no OS or any partitions on my hard drive

Tags: format, troubleshooting

I'm in a sticky situation. Here's the scenario: I have been trying to install Ubuntu mini 13.04 on my Dell Latitude D810 laptop, but I get stuck after the partitioning screens have gone by. Now here's the real problem. I have no OS on my hard drive or any partitions. And I put my hard drive into an external hard drive, and it won't read. So here's my question: how do I format my hard drive so I can install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can put ubuntu on a flash drive and then boot it from that flash drive without installing it to your hard drive and take any corrective actions using the os running from your flash drive.

To create a bootable flash drive using another windows pc, follow these instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Then, next time you boot your latitude, you will have to tell your laptop to use the flash drive to boot. This will likely involve pressing a button as the computer boots (the splash screen will probably tell you which button).

Once you are running ubuntu from your flash drive, you can use a utility such as gparted to format your hard drive or take any other action

Comment: Everything worked fine until I used gparted. When I opened gparted, it would scan for devices and never load. And it gets an error saying Libparted Bug Found! 
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc

Comment: Hmm, well unfortunately I'm not an expert with gparted, so I'm not sure what's going wrong there. You could try an alternative to gparted http://alternativeto.net/software/gparted/ . The current partition table might just be messed up, and it might be possible to fix with software (I am not an expert on that), or your hard drive could be physically broken - thankfully it's not too hard to replace a hard drive.

Comment: I ran a few tests on my hard drive and it turns out I have no write permission. Thank you for all of your help, though.